# Safari loads full html5 video from the page and doesn't allow to use it until loading is finished

Tags: html, video, safari, loading, preload

Only in Safari, I have an issue when it starting to download full video and doesn't allow use the page.
It noticed with autoplay videos on the page and videos where the user should press the play button on the other page...

preload='none' - doesn't help;

tried to use preload='none'

the expected result is to stop loading the video

Comment: code example:

<video autoplay='', playsinline='', loop='', controlslist='nodownload'>
            <source src="http...webm">
    
            <source src="http...mp4">
    
</video>

Comment: issue noticed even if video is paused;

Comment: do you have an example where we can see this problem? is the video encoded with the MOOV atom at the beginning (often referred to as `faststart`)? also, just as a note, usually `autoplay`, `playsinline`, and `loop` are binary attributes... if present, assume `true`, if absent then `false`